# Geiser and Racket variable have been defined previously and cannot be redefined

Tags: emacs, racket, geiser

I'm trying to use geiser-mode in emacs to run racket code.
I've been able to install geiser-mode and launched racket.

Yet when I run a definition twice I got the following error.
    this name was defined previously and cannot be re-defined

here is simple example

```
 (define  a (* 1 4))
 a
```

run twice

In the debugger

```
#a: this name was defined previously and cannot be re-defined
#in: a
```

Answer (score 1):

`racket` *appears* to behave differently in a file and the REPL. This file will throw an error:

```
#lang racket

(define a 5)
(define a 6)
```

And this REPL session will not:

```
> (define a 5)
> a
5
> (define a 6)
> a
6
```

The behavior is because of the way [modules](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._module-syntax%29) work. When working in a file, there is an implicit module. Once the symbol `a` has been defined in that module another symbol with the same name cannot be defined within that module. The [REPL](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval.html?q=repl#%28tech._repl%29) simply [expands forms](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/__top-interaction.html?q=repl#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._~23~25top-interaction%29%29) without all the ceremony of [modules](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/module.html?q=repl#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._~23~25module-begin%29%29).